# Python Selenium Dropdown Menu Last Element Selection

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, drop-down-menu

I am attempting to select an element that is not displayed in the default menu. The element is the last one and won't show up unless scrolled down. I can change the element number but it does not update the table values of the element number. Below is the code I tried. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!! Looked through some of the questions and could not replicate any working solutions.
Screenshot:
[Page Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XwCp.png)

Code below:

```
week_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SEARCH"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", week_dropdown)
page_value_span = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SEARCH"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span[2]')
page_value_edit = driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML = "1";', page_value_span)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",page_value_span)
```

```html
<div span="8" class="ant-row ant-row-end" style="padding-top: 10px;"><div class="style_reportOptionBlock__1Qm2T" style="margin-right: 20px;"><label class="style_vlabelfull__1uP_p">#Weeks: </label><div class="ant-select style_vSelectSearchnew__3UstT ant-select-single ant-select-show-arrow" style="width: 60px;"><div class="ant-select-selector"><span class="ant-select-selection-search"><input autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_1_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_1_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_1_list_-1" readonly="" unselectable="on" value="" id="rc_select_1" style="opacity: 0;" aria-expanded="false"></span><span class="ant-select-selection-item" title="4">4</span></div><span class="ant-select-arrow" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"><span role="img" aria-label="down" class="anticon anticon-down ant-select-suffix"><svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" class="" data-icon="down" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M884 256h-75c-5.1 0-9.9 2.5-12.9 6.6L512 654.2 227.9 262.6c-3-4.1-7.8-6.6-12.9-6.6h-75c-6.5 0-10.3 7.4-6.5 12.7l352.6 486.1c12.8 17.6 39 17.6 51.7 0l352.6-486.1c3.9-5.3.1-12.7-6.4-12.7z"></path></svg></span></span></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you share HTML in text format ?

Comment: I edited the post and included the HTML. title="4" seems to correspond with the dropdown elements as 4 is the default value. I would like to navigate to 1.

Comment: what is the error stacktrace ?

Comment: Can you check if `//span[@class='ant-select-selection-item' and text()='1']` is present only once in DOM ?

Comment: Fug, just shut down my computer. It wasn’t giving any error as the 1 would appear in the dropdown box but the table wouldn’t update with the corresponding values. When I get up tomorrow I’ll reply first thing.

Comment: "ant-select-selection-item" is in it twice, "<li title="1" " is in it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the with `ActionChains`

```
week_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath for open dropdown...").click()

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ant-select-item ant-select-item-option']/div[text()='1']")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(to_element=element)
actions.click(on_element=element).perform()
```

Make sure to import `ActionChains`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

You may also try with `arguments[0].scrollIntoView()`

```
week_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath for open dropdown...").click()

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ant-select-item ant-select-item-option']/div[text()='1']")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', element)
```

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: I tried the scrollIntoView() method and it worked. I really appreciate the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to scroll through the menu, then put a small wait first before clicking/selecting that last option. Let me know if this works ?

Comment: I added two sleeps and it still changes the element to 1 but table doesn't refresh: week_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SEARCH"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", week_dropdown)
page_value_span = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SEARCH"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span[2]')
time.sleep(3)
page_value_edit = driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML = "1";', page_value_span)
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",page_value_span)

Comment: Can you post the full test script consisting of the page you are visiting ? Let me try in my machine. It is hard to analyse just by looking at the xpath . . .

Comment: Unfortunately it is a site that requires a user/pass. Currently trying to mess with scrollintoview to see if that is a better approach.